# Euler's definition of complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone help? Need to find the answer of
$$\frac{e^{iz} + e^{iz}}{2} \ .$$

Comment: What is your question? What do you mean by the answer of an expression?

Comment: Is it $e^{iz}$?

Comment: please reformat, we're not sure what the questions is.  As it looks now, $(e^{iz} + e^{iz})/2 = (2e^{iz})/2 = e^{iz}$

Comment: By the way,  $\cos z=(e^{iz}+e^{\pmb-iz})/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simply $e^{iz}$ (though I suspect a typo)
This is because there are two copies of the term in the numerator, which cancels with the 2 in the denominator.
Then, simplification can be done using $e^{iz}=\cos(z)+i\sin(z)$ which is Euler's formula.

However, if you meant $(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})/2$ the answer is $\cos z$

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjQTWtW_x9o)

Comment: Then what is (e^z - e^-z)/2

Comment: That is sinh (z)

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{aligned}\dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}&=\cos z\\\dfrac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}&=\sin z\end{aligned}$$

Therefore, we have $i\sin z=1/2\cdot \left[e^{iz}-e^{-iz}\right]$.

---

$$\dfrac{e^z-e^{-z}}{2}=\sinh z$$